# UISplitViewController wrong value for the frame of PrimaryViewController view

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a UISplitViewController with 2 custom viewControllers. When I go to setup the primary view controller and want to get the frame of the view, it gives me a totally odd value and when using it to draws the content partly off screen.

Here is my setup in storyboard

[image]

Here is the code for drawing the primary viewController

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
}


override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    print( "view bounds:\(view.frame)")
    let testView = UIView(frame: view.frame.insetBy(dx: 30, dy: 30 ))
    testView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.3)
    view.addSubview( testView )
    
}
```

Here is an image of what is drawn, The two inset rects are expected to be in the bounds of the view.

[image]

Oddly enough when I go to inspect the view hierarchy it shows an odd layout for the PrimaryViewController

[image]

And here is a link to a simple test project:

[enter link description here](https://www.chorusapp.co.uk/SplitViewTest.zip)

Any Ideas of how to get the correct frame for the view for the primaryViewController.

Thanks

Reza

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same problem, but it was solved by restricting all the elements that would enter the primary view controller based on the safeayoutguide

Answer (score 0):

The primary column contains a 100-pt offscreen buffer which can be read by calling view’s safeAreaInsets.left. This will return a value of 100, and adjusting the frames using this value resolves this issue.

Comment: Can you please show the code which did this? I am not sure this is a right solution. Also posted similar question https://stackoverflow.com/q/74162761/1162044